# PHP: Remove excessive <br> tags

Tags: php, regex

I got some "unclean" html string i need to clean up.

I want to replace "more than 2" html linebreaks in a row with 2 html linebreaks.

So the following string:

```
$string = 'ytefey soeije hesouhodeseojedowe<br><br>
 <br>ioueshe oiwj<br /><br />oijeewje<br /><br> <br>  <br>';
```

Should end up something like this:

```
$string = 'ytefey soeije hesouhodeseojedowe<br><br>
ioueshe oiwj<br /><br />oijeewje<br><br>   ';
```

So far i got this:

```
$string = preg_replace('#(<br>|<br />){2,}#i', '<br><br>', $string);
```

But it doesnt take linebreaks and spaces into account.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) with a simple regex:

```
/(<br>\s*|<br \/>\s*){3,}/i
```

Basically it either matches `<br>` or `<br />`(`(<br>|<br \/>)`) with zero or more spaces in front of them(`\s*`) at least 3 or more times(`{3,}`).

```
$string = preg_replace("/(<br>\s*|<br \/>\s*){3,}/i", "<br><br>", $string);
```

Comment: Friend, you saved me! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The following works for any kind of line feed in the string and is faster because it has no matching groups which PCRE has to remember.

```
<?php

$string = "
ytefey soeije hesouhodeseojedowe<br><br>
<br>ioueshe oiwj<br /><br />oijeewje<br /><br> <br>  <br>

foo<br           />

<br />

bar<br/>


";

// @see https://regex101.com/r/vR6rU5/2
$string = preg_replace_all('/(?:<br\s*\/?>(?:\s|\R)*){2,}/iu', "<br><br>", $string);

// Maybe trim excessive line feeds and breaks at the beginning and end?
// @see https://regex101.com/r/uS9jW0/1
$string = preg_replace('/(?:^\R*(?:<br\s*\/?>)*|(?:<br\s*\/?>)*\R*$)/iu', "", $string);

print_r($string);
// ytefey soeije hesouhodeseojedowe<br><br>ioueshe oiwj<br><br>oijeewje<br><br>foo<br><br>bar
```